# Create an object from JSON response, modify values, and return it in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

In an app I recently developed, the client wanted to be able to create a NEW user in their POS system. Their POS system is web-based and has a massive API, so this was easy.

Now they want the app to see if the user exists before creating a duplicate user, which is fine. However, they also want to update the information in the user record if it is a duplicate.

The POS system's API returns an extensive "Customer" JSON response with 250+ fields. I only need to update 4 of those fields.

Is there a way to easily create an object from the "Get Customer" response (it is a multi-dimensional array), edit specific values, and then post that object back as JSON to the "Update Customer" method?

***Edit #1***

Still having problems wrapping my head around this. To further clarify the process and how it works:

`1) API call to get user information
 2) User information returned via JSON. The response is a REALLY big, multi-dimensional, response.
 3) 4 of the fields in the returned JSON customer have to be edited
 4) JSON then needs to be used to create "Parameters" to PUT/POST back to the API.`

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var existingCustomer = NSMutableDictionary()

...Function to acquire JSON using Alamofire...

var json = JSON(response!)
let d = json["Customer"]["Customer"].dictionaryValue

for (k, v) in d {
    if let value = v.string {
        self.existingCustomer[k] = value
    }
    //CHECK FOR OTHER TYPES
}
```

This works to make the dictionary look similar to the JSON, however I am concerned about the multi-dimensional aspect of the Customer JSON. I am not sure that `value`, once checked for being a `dictionaryObject` will be keep it's K,V relationship. I haven't tested yet though.

Once I get the `existingCustomer` Dictionary complete, I can then iterate through the entries to create the params to POST/PUT, however, again, they need to retain their KV relationship.

The params generally look like:

```
var params = [
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Appleseed",
    "photos": [
        "url":"www.website.com",
        "width":1024,
        "height":768
    ],
    "addresses": [
        "shippingAddress": [
            "street":"123 Test Road"
        ],
        "homeAddress": [
            "street":"456 Test Crescent"
        ]
    ],
    "phone":"555-555-5555"
]
```

Only much, much longer. There's something like 200 KVs

Comment: Do you not have a customer model that gets populated from the response?

Comment: Yes. The response contains the Customer model in JSON form. The dilemma is that I have to edit some of the "fields" / "values", and then the whole object back as JSON. When I POST the updated Customer back to their API server, it has to be valid JSON, and every single one of the original key/value pairs that was provided in the "Get Customer" has to be returned in the "Update Customer" method. Any sets that get missed update in their DB as "null". So if I don't send back the phone number field, their server nulls out any existing value for "phone number".

Comment: Okay, so is there an issue with creating a mutablecopy of the response, editing the keys you need, and sending that back?

Comment: Do json serializae in nsmutabledictionary and after that try to edit key/value in dictionary.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm still having issues with this. I'm relatively new to iOS development so I'm still learning. I'm using AlamoFire to call the URL that returns the JSON. I usually then convert the JSON to "SwiftyJSON". I imagine I have to iterate through the JSON, adding each K,V pair to a NSMutableDictionary. Am I on the right train of thought with this? Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly the reason I created the [Aldwych](https://github.com/sketchytech/Aldwych_JSON_Swift) repository. You can edit JSON in a type safe manner and export as received. I can provide assistance if you need it.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow that repo looks like it could work well for my application. I will give it a try.

Comment: Edited the question to give a bit more detail. Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @GoodByeStackOverflow's `Aldwych` repository, I was able to get this solved fairly easily. I was able to directly modify a cloned version of the JSON object and then send it back to the API server as an NSDictionary.